# Query to split a field and lookup on individual codes in that field

Tags: sql, oracle

| states | Firstname | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IL,AL | John | Smith |
| AK,TX | Mary | Peter |

Need a pl/sql query that outputs results as follows. Assume a state lookup exists with Code and Name (Like, AL | Alabama). Please advise.

| statesname | Firstname | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Illinois, Alabama | John | Smith |
| Alaska,Texas | Mary | Peter |

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query and match the state codes and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT ( SELECT LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
                  ORDER BY INSTR(','||t.states||',', ','||s.code||',')
                )
         FROM   states s
         WHERE  INSTR(','||t.states||',', ','||s.code||',') > 0
       ) AS states,
       firstname,
       lastname
FROM   table_name t;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (states, Firstname, LastName) AS
SELECT 'IL,AL', 'John', 'Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AK,TX', 'Mary', 'Peter' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE states (code, name) AS
SELECT 'IL', 'Illinois' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AL', 'Alabama'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AK', 'Alaska'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TX', 'Texas'    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| STATES | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Illinois,Alabama | John | Smith |
| Alaska,Texas | Mary | Peter |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F_kW50kE)

Answer (score 0):

You need a table or (in this case) a cte defining codes and names of states. Join your table data with state names using ON clause as below. Use LISTAGG() to  get state names instead of codes. There is (just in case) replacement of possible space char in your STATES column with empty string.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (STATES, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS 
        ( Select 'IL,AL', 'John', 'Smith' From Dual Union All
          Select 'AK,TX', 'Mary', 'Peter' From Dual Union All
          Select 'AK, IL, TX', 'Jane', 'Doe' From Dual        -- separator with space character
        ), 
    states (STATE_CODE, STATE_NAME) AS
        ( Select 'AL', 'Alabama'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'AK', 'Alaska'   From Dual Union All
          Select 'IL', 'Illinois' From Dual Union All
          Select 'TX', 'Texas'    From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--      M a i n   S Q L :
Select  LISTAGG(s.STATE_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.STATE_CODE)  "STATES", t.FIRST_NAME, t.LAST_NAME
From    tbl t
Inner Join states s ON(InStr(',' || Replace(t.STATES, ' ', '') || ',', ',' || s.STATE_CODE || ',') > 0)
Group By t.STATES, t.FIRST_NAME, t.LAST_NAME
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
STATES                  FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME
----------------------  --------------  -------------
Alabama,Illinois        John            Smith 
Alaska,Texas            Mary            Peter       
Alaska,Illinois,Texas   Jane            Doe         */
```